# JSP to PDF Conversion

Tags: jsp, pdf

I am facing the problem of JSP to PDF Conversion. Here I am developing a web application in which there is a functionality ***SAVE AS PDF***. When we click on that button or link I want to convert JSP pages to PDF format.

Comment: Do you mean that in a jsp you want to be able to generate a pdf?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) library.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if your data is XML, use XSL-FO to generate the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Or use [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?group_id=102)

Answer (score 0):

There are PDF drivers available that you could use to provide this functionality.  [PDF995](http://www.pdf995.com/) is one that comes to mind.